# Getting the Get Variable's Name

Tags: php

i have a need to get an undefined $_GET['$VARIABLE'].

so that if a link comes into item.php?changingitemstyle=10101010101010

I need to find out how to extract the name of the variable not the value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`array_keys()` function](http://docs.php.net/array_keys) to retrieve an array of the keys of an array.

Answer (score 1):

figured it out

php function array_keys

Answer (score 1):

$_GET is a dictionary, so you can get the keys easily enough (unless I'm misunderstanding the question):

```
foreach( $_GET as $var_name => $value ) {
   // Do something here
}
```

Comment: In PHP this data type is called associative array.